# Displaying dates nicely in Django's admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

With methods on your model that return boolean values, you can mark them as boolean so the admin's list displays show the pretty icons, like this [example from the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def born_in_fifties(self):
        return self.birthday.strftime('%Y')[:3] == '195'
    born_in_fifties.boolean = True
```

If a model has a [`DateTimeField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield), then it gets nicely formatted in the list displays.

However, if I've got a method on a model which returns a `datetime`, it shows up in list displays with yyyy-mm-dd values (e.g. 2010-03-16), which isn't very nice to read.

Is there some built-in way to mark a method as returning a `datetime`, similar to what exists for methods which return booleans?

Answer (score 2):

Well, can't you just use:

```
from django.utils.dateformat import *
class Person(models.Model):
    birthday = models.DateField()
    ...

    def format_birthday(self):
        return format(self.birthday, "D d M Y")
```

For what it is worth: untested. Did it from memory...

---

PS. If you want to add some HTML in there, all you need to do is something like:

```
def format_birthday(self):
    return "<b>%s</b>" % format(self.birthday, "D d M Y")
format_birthday.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. I was just wondering if there's an equivalent to the way you denote methods as returning `datetimevalues` like there is for booleans.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm sure the django core people would entertain a patch though...